# folder redirect problem

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect all the files and sub folders of a folder named scripts which is not in root directory means:

from

```
http://localhost/(any folder)/(another any folder)/scripts/script.js
```

to

```
http://localhost/scripts/script.js
```

becasue I have placed the scripts folder in the root of the server.

Comment: Almost sounds like you're trying to fix an misunderstanding about relative and absolute URLs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about :

```
RewriteRule .*/scripts/(.*)$ scripts/$1
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule /[^/]+/[^/]+/scripts/(.+)$ /scripts/$1 [L]
```

Comment: noo.. you're not getting.. i want to redirect all the files of scripts folder to the original folder which is in the root dir.